# accordion-toggles - Jquery active?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created an accordion using Reusable Content in SharePoint 2010 and all is working well except the accordion-toggles which are not behaving. I think I know why however I don't know enough coding to be able to fix it. I need to (I think) put a new function maybe for all panels that are not active and put the plus sign in. I have the following code and my accordion-toggle rotate w(or should) for each time the accordion panel is opened and closed. When the panel is active it should be a plus sign, when it's not active it should be a minus sign and it should transition smoothly between the two.
I have attached all my code if someone can help me out?`

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".accordion-heading").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.panel2').slideToggle('fast');
    $(".accordion-heading").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.panel2').slideUp('fast');



  });

});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can u please try below code

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
$( ".accordion-heading").on('click', function (e) {
    $return = true;
    $( "#accordion .panel2").slideUp();
    $(".accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
    if($(this).next('div').is(':visible')== false)
    {
        $return = false;
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('div').stop(true,false).slideDown();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#accordion  .accordion-heading").removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    return $return;
});
});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::before{
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion-heading.active .accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {

  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel2 {
  display: none;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" >Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" ">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"  >Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" >
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working great in IE however chrome is doing something strange with the icons. Do I need to make any adjustments for Chrome to work as well? Sorry to be a pain. IE is working great!

Comment: It's now working in Chrome - must have been a caching issue. The only thing it won't do is if you want to close the active one? Do you know an easy way to do that? Thank you for all your help so far!!

Comment: I edited my answer and it's work as you want please check once... if it's helpful to you, give a upvote as well as right also...

Answer (score 0):

Just update below code in your js and remove the inline style from the `panel2` divs and remove `collapsed` class from the  a tag with have class `.accordion-toggle`

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.accordioncollapse').hide(); //added

  $(".accordion-heading").click(function() {

  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed'); //added

  $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.panel2').slideToggle('fast');
  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.panel2').slideUp('fast');

  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).find('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('collapsed'); //added
  
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle " aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Is there any way to have the opposite happen with the icons? i.e when you open the panel the icon is a minus sign and when it's closed it's a plus. Sorry, I'm so bad at this stuff....trying to learn all I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it work ok in Chrome for you? Mine still has buggy icons and I've refreshed - even restarted my PC. Very strange.

Comment: I'm going to leave it for the night for now - thank you so much for your help!! I appreciate it and hope you have a good night!

Comment: This one works really well apart from the icon, when you close the active panel the icon stays a minus when it should go back to a plus. Are you able to have a look? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Now I just need it to expand all panels when the user edits it in a SharePoint page! If you know of any way please let me know otherwise I can't thank you enough!! I will mark this as answered!